# Is there possible to use FSEventStreamCreate without NSString

Tags: c++, core-foundation

My project is **not arc or cocoa**, so I don't want use `NSString` in my code, but it seems not work. 
The Xcode shows `"ERROR: (CFStringGetTypeID() != CFGetTypeID(cfStringRef)) (i = 0)"`. 
How should I create the CFString?

The code as follows:

```
const char *path = m_directory.AsCharPtr();

CFStringRef directory = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault,path,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFArrayRef pathsToWatch = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, (const void **)directory, 1, NULL);

void *appPointer = this;
FSEventStreamContext context = {0, appPointer, NULL, NULL, NULL};
FSEventStreamRef stream;
CFAbsoluteTime latency = 1.0; /* Latency in seconds */

/* Create the stream, passing in a callback */
stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, &fsevents_callback,
                             &context,
                             pathsToWatch,
                             kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, /* Or a previous event ID */
                             latency,
                             kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents /* Flags explained in reference */
                             );
```

Answer (score 1):

`CFArrayCreate()` expects **an array** whose elements are arbitrary pointers, hence `void **`. However, in:

```
CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, (const void **)directory, 1, NULL);
```

you’re passing a single element instead of an array. Note that since the function expects an array, it dereferences the address in the second argument, offsetting it to iterate over the array. Remember the `array[i]` is equivalent to `*(array + i)`; in particular, `array[0]` is equivalent to `*array`.

The general solution is to create an array and pass it to the function like so:

```
const void *directories[] = {directory};
CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, directories, 1, NULL);
```

But since the array has a single element, you can also write:

```
CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorMalloc, (const void **)&directory, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: O, My god! What's a newer's error. I didn't note that. Thank you!